# ViewPager updates listView in fragment B from a fragment A

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two Fragments. On the first one, there are buttons (it is a menu) and they represent different categories. On the second one, it is a listView which display data.
I am looking for a way to change the data to display on the listView when the user click on one of the menu items. 
For example : the user click on the menu item 1 (fragment 1), the listView on the fragment 2 have to be updated with the corresponding data.

I read the documentations from [Google Android developer about fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) but I couldn't work it out, I didn't find a solution to my problem.

Maybe I'm missing something ?

EDIT : I tried to clear my ListView by clearing the list of data (ArrayList> listItems) with listItems.clear(). I didn't find how to do adapter.clear(), it seems that this method doesn't exist in the class Adapter.

So to summarize : I created an update method in my fragment which contains the ListView (Fragment2). I called it through a callback method in the main activity, that part seems to work (I checked it with debug mode).
In the update method of my Fragment 2, I clear data with listItems.clear() and then the OnActivityCreated() of the fragment is executed. In it, there is the call of my thread which download data and then it create the ListView in OnPostExecute.

Here is a sample of my code (fragment2) :

```
// After data are ready
lvListe = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvListe);
lvListe.setSelected(true);
lvListe.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(),
getActivity().getBaseContext(), listItems,
     R.layout.affichageitem, new String[] { "image", "title",
                    "subtitle" }, new int[] { R.id.img_title,
                    R.id.titre_main, R.id.soustitre_main });

lvListe.setAdapter(adapter);
lvListe.setClickable(true);

lvListe.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

// Update method :

public void update(String requete, String type)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.requete = requete;

    listItems.clear();
}
```

Comment: @Maxetr can you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The way that I would probably do it is to create a callback method in the `Activity` hosting the `ViewPager` and also a method in the second `Fragment` to update the data.

Then you would call it like:

```
class Fragment1...
{
    ...
    callBackUpdate(data);
}

class Activity...
{
    ...
    public void callBackUpdate(String data)
    {
        Fragment2.update(data);
    }
}

class Fragment2...
{
    ...
    public void update(String data)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

The developers page shows how to create a callback method to the `Activity`.

edit: Actually that's how the Developer's page says to do it.  They create the interface `OnArticleSelectedListener` for the callback.

**edit:** I'm assuming you are using this library for the LazyLoader: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

If so, then you can just add the method to clear the data yourself.  To do so, add a method like this in ListAdapter:

```
public void clear()
{
    data = new String[](); //depends on what data is, if it's a List then just call                             data.clear() for example
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext()); //clear the images
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the adapter that the data has changed
}
```

This might not exactly fit how you currently have it, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created methods callBackUpdate and update in the classes as you described in your answer. The callBackUpdate method is called when I click on a menu item and then the update function of Fragment2 but the ListView is not created again. I tried to clear the list  used by my adapter and then to fill it with new data, but I doesn't work at all :(

Comment: @maxetx can you edit your post to show how you are clearing the data?  Usually it is just `<adapter>.clear(); <adapter>.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I have edited my first post with more explanations about what I wrote and a sample of code.

Comment: Thanks, now that part works but I still can't update the ListView and I don't know why. adapter = new LazyAdapter(...); is called each time and the listItems is well completed with new data. The adapter is updated too but the ListView is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: I've found one problem which can cause this issue. Indeed, when I call the update method, I give it 2 arguments for the query to download data. In the update method of the Fragment2, the arguments are OK but in the onActivityCreated() overriden method, the arguments are Null (they are attributes of my class Fragment2). Then I tried to use in callBackUpdate : Fragment2.setArguments(bundle) with both arguments in the Bundle, but I had the following exception : Fragment already active.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something known as a FragmentTransaction manager at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

and also the FragmentManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Check out some of the questions on stackoverflow related to FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction to figure this out. All you need to do is replace the fragment with a new one which is inflated by a particular xml

Comment: I tried that :
  
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, new ListNewsFragment());
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    
 transaction.commit();

But my ListView is empty when I go back to it.

Comment: Also I would like to directly go back to the fragment B (where the listView is), if I do :

ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
vp.setCurrentItem(1);

The fragment B is displayed before the data are loaded (from the Internet) so the ListView is not updated with the new data and the screen stays black.

Comment: These lines work for me and you seem to be doing right to me :
FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  mainMenu = new ListFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainView, mainMenu).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: The basic solution i can give is that onclick event of any item on the menu replace the fragment B with a new fragment which you want to replace it with using FragmentTransaction and it should work fine.
I am currently using tabs and using the FragmentTransaction to replace One particular fragment with different fragments whenever a different tab is clicked

Comment: @Android2390 This is incorrect. You should never manipulate `Fragment`s from other `Fragment`s directly. They should be manipulated through the `Activity` instead (i.e. implement a callback event as described in the documentation).